# Order one vector of strings by partial match of the other

Tags: r, string-matching

I have two vectors of strings and I need to order one vector by partial match of the other. The vectors look like that:

[image]

So, I need to take each element of the first vector and find its position in `names` in order for both vectors to be in the same order. For instance `GF1` should be `9th` element in the first vector. I know how to order things once the ordering is known. I tried `match` function but it is not working returning me `NAs`:

```
names_order <- match(paste0(samples$groups, samples$mouse), names)
```

I tried also `pmatch` with no success. Probably because `match` searches for full matches. `Grepl` function is not working either:

```
grep(paste0(paste0(samples$groups, samples$mouse), collapse = '|'), names, value = TRUE)
```

Returns just `[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16` which is just where the match is found without the ordering I need.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `grep` and `sapply`:

```
samples$mouse[sapply(samples$groups, function(x) { grep(x, samples$mouse) })]
```

The `grep` base R function is not vectorized with regard to the first parameter, so we can't feed in the entire `groups` vector.  Instead, we can use `sapply` to find the indices of matches in the `mouse` vector of paths.

Comment: I need to order `names` vector by match with `paste0(samples$groups, samples$mouse)` one

Comment: The answer works well, just that the array names should be corrected to sync with the question